# Exibir o ID de outra tabela no DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Como faço para exibir o ID de outra tabela no meu `DataGridView`?
Consigo exibir todos os campos menos o ID.

```
 var novaListaPessoaFisica = listaPessoaFisica.Select(
           pessoaFisica => new
       {

           PessoaFisicaID = pessoaFisica.Pessoa.IDPessoa,
           Nome = pessoaFisica.Nome,
           CPF = pessoaFisica.CPF,
           RG = pessoaFisica.RG,
           DataNascimento = pessoaFisica.DataNascimento
       }).ToList();

    dgvPessoaFisica.DataSource = null;
    dgvPessoaFisica.DataSource = pessoaFisicaCollection;

    dgvPessoaFisica.Update();
    dgvPessoaFisica.Refresh();
    }

    public class PessoaFisica
    {
        public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
        public String Nome { get; set; }
        public String CPF { get; set; }
        public String  RG { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: amigo nos explique mais sobre oque quer fazer, de exemplos, nos mostre como popula o `datagrid`

Comment: você esta criando como o grid na tela?

Comment: Eu quero carregar o meu dataGrid porém quero exibir os dados de outra tabela concretamente o ID por ex: pessoaFisica.Pessoa.ID.

Comment: Não seria só criar mais um campo no seu select?

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta não esta clara, mas se sua intenção é ter mais um campo no seu grid e esse campo já esta na sua *listaPessoaFisica*, então basta que você altere sua consulta com esse campo, `IDPessoa = pessoaFisica.Pessoa.ID,` .

```
var novaListaPessoaFisica = listaPessoaFisica.Select(
           pessoaFisica => new
       {
           IDPessoa = pessoaFisica.Pessoa.ID, 
           PessoaFisicaID = pessoaFisica.Pessoa.IDPessoa,
           Nome = pessoaFisica.Nome,
           CPF = pessoaFisica.CPF,
           RG = pessoaFisica.RG,
           DataNascimento = pessoaFisica.DataNascimento
       }).ToList();
```

Agora se o campo não existe na sua lista e esta em outra tabela você pode usar o fazer um select dentro do seu select para buscar na tabela Pessoa os dados correspondentes, `Pessoa = ctx.Pessoa.FirstOrDefault(P => P.IDPessoa == pessoaFisica.Pessoa.IDPessoa)`

```
var novaListaPessoaFisica = listaPessoaFisica.Select(
                   pessoaFisica => new
                   {
                       Pessoa = ctx.Pessoa.FirstOrDefault(P => P.IDPessoa == pessoaFisica.Pessoa.IDPessoa)
                       PessoaFisicaID = pessoaFisica.Pessoa.IDPessoa,
                       Nome = pessoaFisica.Nome,
                       CPF = pessoaFisica.CPF,
                       RG = pessoaFisica.RG,
                       DataNascimento = pessoaFisica.DataNascimento
                   })
                   .Select(Pf => new
                   {
                       IDPessoa = Pf.Pessoa.IDPessoa
                       PessoaFisicaID = Pf.PessoaFisicaID,
                       Nome = Pf.Nome,
                       CPF = Pf.CPF,
                       RG = Pf.RG,
                       DataNascimento = Pf.DataNascimento
                   }).ToList();
```